# Если запускаю джар файл через cmd то файл не создается

Tags: java, windows, cmd, runtime

Есть джарник, в нем прописанно копирование этого же джарника в другую папку(через Runtime).1случай:Когда я запускаю код без кмд(ком.строки), то файл копируется, но потом не удаляется(удаляю не я,в джарнике прописан алгоритм удаления). И в обоих случаях он не удаляется, ошибок никаких нету. 2случай: Если я запускаю его через cmd(java -jar C:....) то он не копируется, так же и в эклипсе НЕ КОПИРУЕТСЯ(

````
String jarName = new File(Copy.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).getName();
    String jarlocate = new File(jarName).getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(new File(jarName).getAbsolutePath());
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  copy "+jarlocate+" C:\\Users\\%UserName%\\"+jarName);
    p.waitFor();p.destroy();
```вот кусок кода, после него идет другая уже команда с использование runtime, но все их я закрываю
````

Comment: Где прописан алгоритм удаления файла, и я файла перекопированного не вижу, он его типо удаляет, он не говорит, что такого файла не существует.   Можете подказать в чем проблемма может быть?

Comment: Попробуй использовать кавычки в названиях файлов в cmd-команде (экранировать название файла)

Comment: код работает правильно, даже если делать через потоки, а не через процесс, происходит такая же фигня, что с запуском дизайна и кмд, он перестает копировать и удалять файл, а если без кмд и дизайна, то все работает